# how to write conditions on order by clause

Tags: mysql

hi i have a table structure like this

```
id  name         is_file   disp_order   parent
1   PDF Folder   0         2    
2   textpdf1     1         1            1
3   PPT Folder   0         1    
4   testppt1     1         2            3
5   testppt2     1         1            3
```

my requirement is to retrive the data by order i.e files are order by name and folders are 
  order by disp_order

I wrote one query but it will fails if a particular parent has more than 10 children 
   the disp_order is also work as string not numeric one
   Myquery :

```
 select id,nae,is_file,disp_order from contents 
where parent_id=3
order by case 
when is_file=1 then display_text
when is_file=0 then display_order 
end ASC;
```

in my DB parent 3 has 20 records of type folder it fetches the order like this 
   1,10,11,12,2,3,4,5,6,

Comment: Feels that your disp_order is string (or char)

Answer (score 0):

first you order on the display_text, like you want to if is_file = 1. Else you make sure the rows are ordered at the end by putting 'zzz' (could be any string, put 'aaaa' if you want to order them first). Then also order on disp_order.

```
select id,nae,is_file,disp_order from contents 
where parent_id=3
order by case 
when is_file=1 then display_text
when is_file=0 then 'zzz'
end, disp_order;
```

I assumed this is want you want to do. Otherwise provide example output please :)

Comment: thank u it is working as expected, i have doubt on putting strings kind of thing if u know any link about this please share to me that will help me

Comment: well, you have to put the 'zzz' string because display_text is also a string. Putting a case in the order by clause is not a problem, as long as every 'case' results in the same data-type (in this case, string).

Comment: If this answer helped you and/or solved your question, please accept the answer then. That way this question is no longer open, and we can keep the site clean.

Answer (score 0):

To have the sorting done in integer, please try below:

```
select id,nae,is_file,disp_order from contents 
where parent_id=3
order by case 
when is_file=1 then display_text
when is_file=0 then display_order * 1
end ASC;
```

Comment: i tried this one it failed if a folder contains more than 10 folders

Answer (score 0):

This pre-sorts all Is_File = 0 first, then all Is_File = 1 next.  However, WITHIN each group, all files will be sorted by their `name` column, but folders will be sorted by their disp_order.

```
select 
      c.id,
      c.`name`,
      c.is_file,
      c.disp_order,
      c.parent
   from
      contents c
   where
      c.parent=3
   order by
      c.is_file,
      case when is_file = 1 
         then c.`name` else c.display_order end
```